# How to insert an object into a collection Object in Laravel at specific index

Tags: laravel

I have a collection with News items and I want to add a object to a specific index. For example:

```
$item = new NewsItem();
$newsItems->add($item); // to index nr 3
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible.

The better solution is splice your collection at the index, then create a new collection, copy the collection before the index, prepend your new item and, by the end, copy the rest of your collection into the new one.

```
$afterIndex = $newsItems->splice($index);
$newItensCollections = $newsItems;
$newItensCollections->prepend($yourNewItem);
$newItensCollections->union($afterIndex);
```

To splice:
https://laravel.com/docs/master/collections#method-splice

To prepend:
https://laravel.com/docs/master/collections#method-prepend

To copy the arrays:
https://laravel.com/docs/master/collections#method-union

Answer (score 0):

You can use splice to insert an object at a specific location:

```
$newsItems->splice($index, 0, [$item]);
```

`$item` will then be inserted in `$newItems[$index]`

Answer (score 0):

If you already have a Collection and want to prepend or push the value in it

```
$newObject = (object)[
    'key_1' => "Value",
    'key_2' => "10"
];

$existingCollection->push($newObject);
$existingCollection->prepend($newObject);
```